# use conditional statements in model

Tags: php, yii

Is it possible to add conditional statements in Yii  model

for eaxmple :

in users model I need to check if user is admin then in update information Controller
 mobile number field will display as required filed , but if user is normal user change field properties to empty or not required

```
array('mobile','length', 'max'=>14 ,'min'=>3),
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo   (if(isset(admin_session))) ? 'write the update code for admin' : 'write the normal user update code';

Comment: you need to echo before u use if baracket like
echo (if(isset(admin_session))) ? 'write the update code for admin' : 'write the normal user update code';